# Convert Angular HttpClient result

Tags: rxjs

I have the following code:

```
getData(config: IConfig): Observable<IDataItem> {
    return this.http
        .get<IDataItem>(url);
}
```

That works fine. But I need to return a data structure like this:

```
result = {
 id: config.id,
 payload: httpCallPayload
}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/http and https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#operators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map` pipeable operator of `RxJs` like following:

```
getData(config: IConfig) {
    return this.http.get<IDataItem>(url).pipe(
        map((httpResult) => {
            return {
               id: config.id,
               payload: httpResult
            }
        })
    );
}
```

Note that the return type `Observable<IDataItem>` is removed because it will throw an error. You can create an interface for the return type like `{id: string|number, payload: IDataItem}` to define the return type of `getData()` method.

For further reading: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html